# Direct vs Contradiction Proof: For any odd integer n, prove that $\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor = (n^2-1)/4$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

To start things off, I was assigned a "homework" (wait, hear me out first) to use direct proof and proof on contradiction for the following:

> For any odd integer n, prove that $\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor = (n^2-1)/4$.

(I has modified the question to something similar, so this is not my homework question)

Direct proof is easy, just sub $n = 2a+1$ to get the right hand side.

But for proof of contradiction, would it be considered correct to do the same thing?

For example, we assume that $\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor \neq (n^2-1)/4$, then fit in $n=2a+1$ to both sides, and prove that they are equals.

Or should I instead derive $\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor = (n^2-1)/4 + x$ from the assumption, derive the properties of x, and disprove these properties of x?

Comment: I'll "hear you out" , vote you up first. Then, I'll say : if you were proving this by contradiction, you'd start with $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor \neq \frac{n^2-1}{4}$ *and* $n$ odd, and then proceed to find a contradiction. So you can't fit in $n=2a$ (that would already assume that $n$ is even, which you can't do so). You can, indeed, try to derive $x$ from your expression, that sounds like a good exercise. My take on this is different : I think if $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor \neq \frac{n^2-1}{4}$, then you can try to do something with some quantity *between* these two numbers.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Sorry, I'm an idiot. I meant to write $n=2a+1$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer not sure if I'm getting what you meant by quantity between, but I'm assuming what you meant is that the closest integer lesser than $n^2/4$ cannot be $-1/4$ from $n^2/4$ ?

Comment: Perhaps I was wrong, dear @BigLJ. In your revised post, your first approach (substitute $n = 2a+1$) is correct, but it doesn't "sound" like a proof by contradiction, because what you end up with is just $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor = \frac{n^2-1}{4}$, which is just a direct proof of this fact, really. You have my second intention right : assume that $n$ is odd and $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor -\frac{n^2-1}{4} = x \neq 0$. Prove things about $x$ that are contradictory (indeed, one can show that $0<x<1$ and $x$ is an integer).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thanks, I got the gist of it now.